# Router Reload testing

Tags: karma-jasmine

how to test this piece of code in angular karma ?

```
this.router.navigate(['test']).then(()=> {window.location.reload()})
```

My test :

```
let routeSpy = {navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate)}
routeSpy.navigate(['test']).then(() => {window.location.reload()})
```

Error :

```
Cannot read property of undefined (reading then )
```